# After restart of apache server, php script no longer works

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux-2

after (just) restarting my apache server, which runs a php script,
the website no more works.

I can see the landing page, and that's it.
(cannot click buttons, no reaction, no backend entrance..)

I have checked log files of server:
Everything is ok & working.

I have checked log files of apache, and got these errors:

- HTTPD

The timeout specified has expired:

```
[client 2.247.241.109:11131] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling), referer: (ip of my server)
```

Do you know what is going on?

I guessed that apache won't execute php (script) any more, is that correct?

Or is it something different?

Big thanks to anyone who can help me out.

Comment: Have you done any changes to php.ini or apache2.conf/httpd.conf lately? is this a managed server (cpanel etc) or a standard one?

Comment: Also , can you run any php script ? such as "hello world" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
service httpd restart
```

---

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

Make sure no rerwite rules are added in the .htaccess file.